# string comparison using =~ operator

Tags: perl

string comparison using =~ operator

I have  two arrays @a containing abc99_xyz ,abc9_xxx  and @b containing abc99 ,abc9 as a string and I want match only abc99_xyz of array @a with abc99 of @b but abc9 is also getting matched with abc99_xyz of @a when I am using ~= operator.

Code is as below:

```
@a=qw(abc99_xyz abc9_xxx);
@b=qw(abc99 abc9);

foreach $k(@a)
        {

        foreach $h(@b)
        {
        if($k =~ $h)
        {
        print" $k == $h\n";
        }
     }
 }
```

only abc99_xyz should match with abc99 and not abc9.

Comment: @ysth I voted to close for lack of MCVE.

Comment: Hi the result should be abc99_xyz == abc99 not 
  abc99_xyz == abc9

Comment: this is my first time here so may be not able to explain properly forgive me for that

Comment: @ysth Yeah, but there is no question.

Comment: @ikegami,$k =~ /^\Q$h\E_/ and $k =~ /^\Q$h\E(?:_|\z)/ both worked.Thanks a lot

Comment: @ysth, In an answer, I would have mentioned that too :) +1

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you need to adjust your match to require the `_` after the matched string.

```
my @strings = ( 'abc99_xyz', 'abc9_xxx');
my @patterns = ( 'abc99', 'abc9' );
for my $string (@strings) {
    for my $pattern (@patterns) {
        if ( $string =~ /^\Q$pattern\E_/ ) {
            print "$string == $pattern\n";
        }
    }
}
```

In the match, the `^` says the pattern must match at the beginning of the string, the `\Q`/`\E` make any special characters in `$pattern` such as `*` match literally, and the `_` makes it require a `_` in the string immediately after `$pattern`.

If you have many strings and/or patterns, it would be better to find the part of each string before the _ and use a hash lookup:

```
my @strings = ( 'abc99_xyz', 'abc9_xxx');
my %patterns = ( 'abc99' => 1, 'abc9' => 1 );
for my $string (@strings) {
    if ( $string =~ /^([^_]+)/ && $patterns{$1} ) {
        print "$string == $1\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: `%patterns` can be built from an array using `my %patterns = map { $_ => 1 } @patterns;`